# Which INL is better for this ADC?

Tags: adc, accuracy

I am using the following [ADC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads112c04.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1684524837285).

1. I want to know given the figures below, which INL is better?
2. How do I interpret the x-axis (% of FS)? What is my full-scale (FS) value? My Vin ranges from 10mV to 50mV RMS

[image]

EDIT 1:
Is the FS just the reference voltage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FSR is defined as +/-Vref/Gain (so 2*Vref/Gain)

INL as a percentage of full scale gets worse as the gain increase, but in absolute terms it appears to not change much with gain when the internal reference is used.

It does appear to be significantly better with an external reference.

Keep in mind that the *worst* INL shown there is about 5 or 6 ppm of 4.096V, which is really pretty good for a 16-bit ADC.

Comment: Where did you get the 4.096V from?

Comment: 2 * 2.048V (the internal reference voltage).